# How to lowercase a variable dplyr and sparklyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, sparklyr

Using a spark dataframe, how do I user the lower case a variable? Here is the code I am trying

```
df <- df %>% 
mutate(newLowerCase = base::tolower(OriginalString))
```

The error message is

```
Error in base::tolower(OriginalString) : object 'OriginalString' not found
```

Any comments please let me know.

Comment: So is `OriginalString` the name of a column in that data frame?

Comment: Yes, that is the variable name.

Comment: It's unclear how this question relates to sparklyr.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df$newLowerCase <- tolower(df$OriginalString)
```